# There aren't any desktop or taskbar icons after restarting, and my terminal won't open. What's the deal?

Tags: 20.04, icons

I'm a complete beginner to Linux and just installed 20.04 on a partition. I install it, all's well, but the terminal won't open. I figure restarting might fix it, and now there are no icons anywhere. Not on my desktop, taskbar, show applications. Not on the login screen, not on the activities bar. What's up with this?

Comment: If you can get to the activities bar, then you can type in terminal.  Hopefully that matches the terminal program and you have a starting point.   My guess is that one of the drives or partitions on your system has an error, and if you require it to mount, then it may delay the desktop from opening up.  When you get the terminal up, then try typing    dmesg   to display messages from the current boot up.

Comment: @mondotofu The terminal doesn't open from anywhere. Taskbar, applications, ctrl alt t. I'll probably just reinstall it and try again.